# Js test driver plugin for eclipse ganymade

Tags: eclipse, junit, testing

I have been trying with the below update links.
But they are not working.
Is there any latest plugin available?

- http://js-test-driver.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.2
- http://js-test-driver.googlecode.com/svn/update/

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [Using the Eclipse plugin](http://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/wiki/UsingTheEclipsePlugin) page for js-test-driver, the correct update site is:

http://js-test-driver.googlecode.com/svn/update/

But the following comment shows it may have been developed/tested mainly for Galileo (3.5) and not for Ganymede (3.4).

> > do you support Eclipse 3.5? In eclipse's preference there is no Server Panel
>
> Yeah, we support Eclipse 3.5, I work extensively (almost exclusively) on it.
> Eclipse preferences should have a JS Test Driver, not a Server panel. The server panel is part of the JS Test Driver View.